Forwarding an SSL domain on GoDaddy
I have a site hosted on GoDaddy, example.com. I need to redirect all traffic from example.com to newsite.com.
I attempted to set up a 301 redirect on GoDaddy from example.com to newsite.com. This works for http: but hangs on https: (newsite.com is currently redirecting http: to https: correctly).
Do I need to remove the SSL certificate from example.com to get this to work? Or is there another config step I'm missing?

If your old site (example.com) had HSTS (HTTP Strict Transport Security) enabled, it means that browsers are instructed to only connect to it via HTTPS. This might interfere with the redirection process to newsite.com, especially if the SSL certificate on example.com is not valid or properly configured.
